# "Помашешь" или "помахаешь"?

Tags: глаголы, времена

Как правильно употреблять глагол "помахать" в будущем времени: "Ты мне помахаешь" или "Ты мне помашешь"?

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Информация из Интернета

У глагола махать есть две формы : одна старая, уходящая корнями в историю, — машут, а другая новая — махают. Старая форма (машут) считается нормой всегда и везде — это классика. А новая (махают), совсем недавно ещё входившая в набор неправильностей, сегодня допустима, но не всегда и не везде, а только в обиходе, в разговорной речи.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Глагол "махать" относится к  глаголам с вариантными формами спряжения.  Другие примеры: брызгает и брызжет,  колыхается и колышется, плескает и плещет, метает и мечет, рыскает и рыщет.Вариантные формы спряжения различаются по стилю или по смыслу. Так, формы глагола "махать" различаются по стилю (машет - нейтральный и махает - разговорный). Формы глагола "двигать" различаются по смыслу: пружина часов движет стрелку, но человек двигает пальцами.

Answer (score 2):

Помашешь и доп. помахаешь.
Так написано в Орфоэпическом словаре.

На мой взгляд, "помахаешь" звучит просторечно.